# Linear Algebra Conditions

Tags: linear-algebra

The question:

[image]

I know that the answers is b) ab≠1, but I have no clue how to get to that answer... Can someone help me?

Comment: Do you know what a determinant is?

Comment: Compute the determinant $D$ of the system. You get $D=\left|\matrix{1&b\cr 2a&2}\right|$ and you want the condition $D\neq0$ to hold.

Answer (score 1):

The coefficient matrix has to have non-zero determinant in order to have a unique solution. This yields
$$
2-2ab\neq 0
$$
which is equivalent to 
$$
ab\neq 1
$$

Answer (score 0):

We can proceed by finding the rank of this system as:

$$\begin{array}{ccc}
1 & b & | -1\\
2a & 2  & | 5\end{array}$$
$$\Rightarrow \begin{array}{ccc}
1 & b & | -1\\
0 & 2-2ab & | 5 + 2a\end{array}$$ performing the operation $R_2 \to R_2-2aR_1$.

Now, *if this system is to have an unique solution*, we must have that Rank$_A =$ Rank$_{A:b} =$ order of matrix $A = 2$. Thus, $2-2ab \neq 0 \Rightarrow ab\neq 1$.

**Also note, that this is the same condition of** $|A| \neq 0$. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Thank to all for the responses. Also [these guys](http://domyhomeworkfor.me/) helped me so answer is that this can easily be done with determinants. If a square matrix's determinant does not equal zero, then that square matrix will have an inverse hence having a unique solution. Since this is a 2x2 matrix, just compute the determinant with the condition that it cannot equal zero:
(1)(2)-(2ab) =/= 0
2 =/= 2ab
1=/= ab

Answer (score 0):

For two simultaneous equations,
a1x+b1y=c1
a2x+b2y=c2
The condition for then having one solution is 
a1/a2 not equal to b1/b2

So 1/2a not equal to b/2
 Which gives you , 
ab not equal to 1